# Rearrange HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a `JSON` data like this:

```
var data = [
    {"city":"seattle", "state":"WA", "population":652405, "land_area":83.9},
    {"city":"new york", "state":"NY", "population":8405837, "land_area":302.6},
    {"city":"boston", "state":"MA", "population":645966, "land_area":48.3},
    {"city":"kansas city", "state":"MO", "population":467007, "land_area":315}
  ]
```

I have added this `JSON` data into my `HTML` table. Now how can I randomly arrange this data every `5 seconds` when button is clicked?

```
alter.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //code goes here
})
```

Comment: `setTimeout(()=>{//your code}, 5000)` but we need more details

Comment: @stacks i am assuming click.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib This is a TimeOut, it will get called only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `rows` is a nodeList of `tr`

```js
function randomise() {
    for (const row of rows) {
        const table = row.parentElement;
        table.insertBefore(
            row,
            table.children[Math.floor(Math.random() * table.children.length)]
        );
    }
}

alter.addEventListener("click", () => {
    randomise();
    setInterval(function () {
        randomise();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: here is my `HTML`  table  <button type="submit" id="alter" >Sort</button>
    `<table>
            <tr>
                <th> City</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Population</th>
                <th>Land_area</th>
            </tr>
        <tbody id="data"></tbody>
    </table>`

Comment: @kedarsedai if you put your "content" rows in a `tbody` it will work while retaining the headers at the top. See https://codepen.io/kaleidawave/pen/ZEbWRdL?editors=1010

Comment: Okay, it works !!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way how to shuffle you array every 5 seconds after you click your button if you click it multiple times it will always cancel the previous timeout instance

```js
var data = [{
    "city": "seattle",
    "state": "WA",
    "population": 652405,
    "land_area": 83.9
  },
  {
    "city": "new york",
    "state": "NY",
    "population": 8405837,
    "land_area": 302.6
  },
  {
    "city": "boston",
    "state": "MA",
    "population": 645966,
    "land_area": 48.3
  },
  {
    "city": "kansas city",
    "state": "MO",
    "population": 467007,
    "land_area": 315
  }
]



const arrRandomIndex = []
const newArr = [];

while (arrRandomIndex.length !== data.length) {
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
  if (!arrRandomIndex.includes(randomNum)) {
    arrRandomIndex.push(randomNum);
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  newArr[i] = data[arrRandomIndex[i]];
}

let timeId;

document.getElementById('alter').addEventListener('click', function() {
  clearTimeout(timeId);
  timeId = setTimeout(_ => console.log('Random array', newArr), 5000)
})
```

```html
<button id="alter">
AlTER
</button>
```